# Mapping word using controls

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I have a document with a certain structure.
For example with executive summery which contained several paragraphs, Body of the document that include finding, comments and response etc…
I thought about building using vsto “controls” which the user will drag & drop to the document according to his needs.
For example: if he needs to write comments he will drag a control of type of comments to the documents and write his content.
Eventually I need to go over the document and saved his content to the database.

Unfortunately I am new in vsto or word-vba, and I will appreciate your advice if my vision is applicable and if you can give some example or links to start with.

Thanks
Keren

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use either Building Blocks or Content Controls or a combination. Building Blocks can contain Content Controls. For example you could have a "Comments" Building Block, the user could insert the "Comments" Building Block and fill it out. If you use Content Controls you can extract their contents and save it to a database.